# Having an issue creating an exe with py2exe and script importing xlrd

Tags: python, py2exe, xlrd

My goal is to create a python script that loops over cells of an excel document.  This is my python script called `reader.py`, and it works just fine.

```
    import xlrd
    import os

    exceldoc = raw_input("Enter the path to the doc [C:\\folder\\file.xlsx]: ")

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(exceldoc,'rb')
.... some code....
```

The problem I'm encountering is attempting to use py2exe to create an executable so this script can be used elsewhere.

Here is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
from glob import glob

setup(name='Excel Document Checker',console=['reader.py'])
```

I run the following command: `python setup.py py2exe`

It appears to run fine; it creates the `dist` folder that has my `reader.exe` file, but near the end of the command I get the following:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['cElementTree', 'elementtree.ElementTree']
```

I did some searching online, and tried the recommendations here [Re: Error: Element Tree not found](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.py2exe/4430), this changing my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

from glob import glob

options={
    "py2exe":{"unbuffered": True,"optimize": 2,
   'includes':['xml.etree.ElementPath', 'xml.etree.ElementTree', 'xml.etree.cElementTree'],
 "packages": ["elementtree", "xml"]}}

setup(name='Excel Document Checker',options = options,console=['reader.py'])
```

I'm now getting an error:
`ImportError: No module named elementtree`

I'm sort of at an impasse here.  Any help or guidance is greatly appreciate.

Just some information - I'm running Python 2.6 on a 32 bit system.

Comment: just as an aside I have had alot better luck with pyinstaller for building windows executables ...

Comment: Have you installed the third-party version of etree (which is generally newer than what's in the stdlib, so some modules/programs try to import it if possible)? I believe it's named `elementtree` (the [package it comes in](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elementtree/) definitely is), as opposed to the stdlib's `xml.etree`.

Comment: Also, please show us the whole traceback, not just the error string. And tell us _when_ you're getting it—building a bdist? installing? running an installed version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You explicitly told `setup.py` to depend on a package named `elementtree` here:

```
"packages": ["elementtree", "xml"]}}
```

There is no such package in the stdlib. There's `xml.etree`, but obviously that's the same name.

The example you found is apparently designed for someone who has installed the third-party package [`elementtree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elementtree/), which is necessary if you need features added after Python 2.6's version of `xml.etree`, or if you need to work with Python 1.5-2.4, but not if you just want to use Python 2.6's version. (And anyway, if you *do* need the third-party package… then you have to install it or it won't work, obviously.)

So, just don't do that, and that error will go away.

---

Also, if your code—or the code you import (e.g., `xlrd`) is using `xml.etree.cElementTree`, then, as the [`py2exe FAQ`](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules) says, you must also `import xml.etree.ElementTree` before using it to get it working. (And you also may need to specify it manually as a dependency.)

You presumably don't want to change all the third-party modules you're using… but I believe that making sure to `import xml.etree.ElementTree` before importing any of those third-party modules works fine.